# Bootstrap landing page layout issue - Container not fitting screen size properly

Tags: html, frontend, containers, bootstrap-5

I'm currently working on creating a landing page using Bootstrap for practice. However, I'm facing an issue with the layout where the container doesn't fit the appropriate screen size. The right and left sides are unbalanced, causing the screen to lean towards the left side.

Here's a screenshot (link) illustrating the problem: [text](https://prnt.sc/w6RrDv7o5vb5)

I've tried various approaches, but haven't been able to resolve the issue. I suspect it could be a problem with the grid system or container settings in Bootstrap.

Could someone please guide me on how to troubleshoot and fix this layout problem? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, here are some relevant code snippets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Title -->
  <section id="title" class="gradient-background">

    <div class="container col-xxl-8 pt-5">
      <div class="row flex-lg-row-reverse align-items-center">
        
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
          <img src="./images/iphone.png" class="header-img d-block mx-auto img-fluid" alt="Dog on a smartphone" height="200" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-body-emphasis lh-1 mb-3 pt-5 pb-3">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          
          <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-start pb-5">
            
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg px-4 me-md-2">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-apple mb-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43Zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282Z"/>
                <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43Zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282Z"/>
              </svg>
              Download
            </button>
            
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg px-4">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-google-play mb-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M14.222 9.374c1.037-.61 1.037-2.137 0-2.748L11.528 5.04 8.32 8l3.207 2.96 2.694-1.586Zm-3.595 2.116L7.583 8.68 1.03 14.73c.201 1.029 1.36 1.61 2.303 1.055l7.294-4.295ZM1 13.396V2.603L6.846 8 1 13.396ZM1.03 1.27l6.553 6.05 3.044-2.81L3.333.215C2.39-.341 1.231.24 1.03 1.27Z"/>
              </svg>
              Download
            </button>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <!-- Features -->
  <section id="features">
    <div class="row g-4 py-5 row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-3 px-4">
      
      <div class="col d-flex align-items-start py-4">
        <div class="icon-square text-body-emphasis bg-body-secondary d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fs-4 flex-shrink-0 me-3">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check2-circle"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M2.5 8a5.5 5.5 0 0 1 8.25-4.764.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.866A6.5 6.5 0 1 0 14.5 8a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0 5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0z" />
              <path d="M15.354 3.354a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8 9.293 5.354 6.646a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l7-7z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Featured title</h3>
          <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col d-flex align-items-start py-4">
        <div class="icon-square text-body-emphasis bg-body-secondary d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fs-4 flex-shrink-0 me-3">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-mortarboard" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M8.211 2.047a.5.5 0 0 0-.422 0l-7.5 3.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .025.917l7.5 3a.5.5 0 0 0 .372 0L14 7.14V13a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v2h3v-2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1V6.739l.686-.275a.5.5 0 0 0 .025-.917l-7.5-3.5ZM8 8.46 1.758 5.965 8 3.052l6.242 2.913L8 8.46Z"/>
            <path d="M4.176 9.032a.5.5 0 0 0-.656.327l-.5 1.7a.5.5 0 0 0 .294.605l4.5 1.8a.5.5 0 0 0 .372 0l4.5-1.8a.5.5 0 0 0 .294-.605l-.5-1.7a.5.5 0 0 0-.656-.327L8 10.466 4.176 9.032Zm-.068 1.873.22-.748 3.496 1.311a.5.5 0 0 0 .352 0l3.496-1.311.22.748L8 12.46l-3.892-1.556Z"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Featured title</h3>
          <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col d-flex align-items-start py-4">
        <div class="icon-square text-body-emphasis bg-body-secondary d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fs-4 flex-shrink-0 me-3">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-through-heart"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M2.854 15.854A.5.5 0 0 1 2 15.5V14H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.354-.854l1.5-1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 11.5h1.793l.53-.53c-.771-.802-1.328-1.58-1.704-2.32-.798-1.575-.775-2.996-.213-4.092C3.426 2.565 6.18 1.809 8 3.233c1.25-.98 2.944-.928 4.212-.152L13.292 2 12.147.854A.5.5 0 0 1 12.5 0h3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 1-.854.354L14 2.707l-1.006 1.006c.236.248.44.531.6.845.562 1.096.585 2.517-.213 4.092-.793 1.563-2.395 3.288-5.105 5.08L8 13.912l-.276-.182a21.86 21.86 0 0 1-2.685-2.062l-.539.54V14a.5.5 0 0 1-.146.354l-1.5 1.5Zm2.893-4.894A20.419 20.419 0 0 0 8 12.71c2.456-1.666 3.827-3.207 4.489-4.512.679-1.34.607-2.42.215-3.185-.817-1.595-3.087-2.054-4.346-.761L8 4.62l-.358-.368c-1.259-1.293-3.53-.834-4.346.761-.392.766-.464 1.845.215 3.185.323.636.815 1.33 1.519 2.065l1.866-1.867a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L5.747 10.96Z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Featured title</h3>
          <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Testimonial -->
  <section id="testimonial">
    <div class="mb-4 bg-body-tertiary rounded-3">
      <div class="container-fluid py-5 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <h2 class="fs-2 text-center pt-4">"I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof."</h2>
        <img class="profile-img mt-5" src="./images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog image">
        <p class="mt-2 mx-auto">Pebbles, New York</p>
        
        <div class="container pt-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
              <img src="./images/techcrunch.png" alt="TechCrunch" height="30">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
              <img src="./images/mashable.png" alt="Mashable" height="30">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
              <img src="./images/bizinsider.png" alt="Business Insider" height="40">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
              <img src="./images/tnw.png" alt="TNW" height="38">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Pricing -->
  <section id="pricing">
    <div class="container py-3">
      <header>
        <div class="pricing-header p-3 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
          <h2 class="display-4 fw-normal text-body-emphasis">A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
          <p class="fs-5 text-body-secondary">Simple and affordable price plans for you and your dog.</p>
        </div>
      </header>
    
      <main>
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 mb-3 text-center">
          
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h3 class="my-0 fw-normal">Chihuahua</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-title pricing-card-title fs-1">$0<small class="text-body-secondary fw-light">/mo</small></p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>5 Matches Per Day</li>
                  <li>10 Messages Per Day</li>
                  <li>Unlimited App Usage</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h3 class="my-0 fw-normal">Labrador</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15<small class="text-body-secondary fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>Unlimited Matches</li>
                  <li>Unlimited Messages</li>
                  <li>Unlimited App Usage</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-dark">Get started</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm border-primary">
              <div class="card-header py-3 text-bg-dark border-primary">
                <h3 class="my-0 fw-normal">Mastiff</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29<small class="text-body-secondary fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>Pirority Listing</li>
                  <li>Unlimited Matches & Messages</li>
                  <li>Unlimited App Usage</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-dark">Contact us</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <section id="footer" class="gradient-background">
    <div class="container">
      <footer class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-5 py-2 pt-4">
        
        <div class="col mb-3">
          <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none">
            <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
          </a>
          <p class="text-body-secondary">© TinDog</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col mb-3">
        </div>
    
        <div class="col mb-3">
          <h5>Section</h5>
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Features</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">FAQs</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col mb-3">
          <h5>Section</h5>
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Features</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">FAQs</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col mb-3">
          <h5>Section</h5>
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Features</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">FAQs</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>

  </section>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I checked the container syntaxes, margin and padding too. But I can't really figure out what's the problem about it..

I would really appreciate your help and it will help me a lot as a novice..

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horizontal scrollbar appeared because the *Features* section overflowed the body by more than 100%. Add Bootstrap class `mw-100`, equivalent to setting `max-width: 100%;` in CSS.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Title -->
  <section id="title" class="gradient-background">

    <div class="container col-xxl-8 pt-5">
      <div class="row flex-lg-row-reverse align-items-center">

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
          <img src="./images/iphone.png" class="header-img d-block mx-auto img-fluid" alt="Dog on a smartphone" height="200" loading="lazy">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-body-emphasis lh-1 mb-3 pt-5 pb-3">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>

          <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-start pb-5">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg px-4 me-md-2">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-apple mb-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43Zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282Z" />
                  <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43Zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282Z" />
                </svg>
                Download
              </button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg px-4">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-google-play mb-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M14.222 9.374c1.037-.61 1.037-2.137 0-2.748L11.528 5.04 8.32 8l3.207 2.96 2.694-1.586Zm-3.595 2.116L7.583 8.68 1.03 14.73c.201 1.029 1.36 1.61 2.303 1.055l7.294-4.295ZM1 13.396V2.603L6.846 8 1 13.396ZM1.03 1.27l6.553 6.05 3.044-2.81L3.333.215C2.39-.341 1.231.24 1.03 1.27Z" />
                </svg>
                Download
              </button>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <!-- Features -->
  <section id="features">
    <div class="row g-4 py-5 row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-3 px-4 mw-100">

      <div class="col d-flex align-items-start py-4">
        <div class="icon-square text-body-emphasis bg-body-secondary d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fs-4 flex-shrink-0 me-3">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check2-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M2.5 8a5.5 5.5 0 0 1 8.25-4.764.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.866A6.5 6.5 0 1 0 14.5 8a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0 5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0z" />
              <path d="M15.354 3.354a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8 9.293 5.354 6.646a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l7-7z" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Featured title</h3>
          <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col d-flex align-items-start py-4">
        <div class="icon-square text-body-emphasis bg-body-secondary d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fs-4 flex-shrink-0 me-3">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-mortarboard" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M8.211 2.047a.5.5 0 0 0-.422 0l-7.5 3.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .025.917l7.5 3a.5.5 0 0 0 .372 0L14 7.14V13a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v2h3v-2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1V6.739l.686-.275a.5.5 0 0 0 .025-.917l-7.5-3.5ZM8 8.46 1.758 5.965 8 3.052l6.242 2.913L8 8.46Z" />
              <path d="M4.176 9.032a.5.5 0 0 0-.656.327l-.5 1.7a.5.5 0 0 0 .294.605l4.5 1.8a.5.5 0 0 0 .372 0l4.5-1.8a.5.5 0 0 0 .294-.605l-.5-1.7a.5.5 0 0 0-.656-.327L8 10.466 4.176 9.032Zm-.068 1.873.22-.748 3.496 1.311a.5.5 0 0 0 .352 0l3.496-1.311.22.748L8 12.46l-3.892-1.556Z" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Featured title</h3>
          <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col d-flex align-items-start py-4">
        <div class="icon-square text-body-emphasis bg-body-secondary d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fs-4 flex-shrink-0 me-3">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-through-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.854 15.854A.5.5 0 0 1 2 15.5V14H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.354-.854l1.5-1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 11.5h1.793l.53-.53c-.771-.802-1.328-1.58-1.704-2.32-.798-1.575-.775-2.996-.213-4.092C3.426 2.565 6.18 1.809 8 3.233c1.25-.98 2.944-.928 4.212-.152L13.292 2 12.147.854A.5.5 0 0 1 12.5 0h3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 1-.854.354L14 2.707l-1.006 1.006c.236.248.44.531.6.845.562 1.096.585 2.517-.213 4.092-.793 1.563-2.395 3.288-5.105 5.08L8 13.912l-.276-.182a21.86 21.86 0 0 1-2.685-2.062l-.539.54V14a.5.5 0 0 1-.146.354l-1.5 1.5Zm2.893-4.894A20.419 20.419 0 0 0 8 12.71c2.456-1.666 3.827-3.207 4.489-4.512.679-1.34.607-2.42.215-3.185-.817-1.595-3.087-2.054-4.346-.761L8 4.62l-.358-.368c-1.259-1.293-3.53-.834-4.346.761-.392.766-.464 1.845.215 3.185.323.636.815 1.33 1.519 2.065l1.866-1.867a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L5.747 10.96Z" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Featured title</h3>
          <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Testimonial -->
  <section id="testimonial">
    <div class="mb-4 bg-body-tertiary rounded-3">
      <div class="container-fluid py-5 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <h2 class="fs-2 text-center pt-4">"I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof."</h2>
        <img class="profile-img mt-5" src="./images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog image">
        <p class="mt-2 mx-auto">Pebbles, New York</p>

        <div class="container pt-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
              <img src="./images/techcrunch.png" alt="TechCrunch" height="30">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
              <img src="./images/mashable.png" alt="Mashable" height="30">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
              <img src="./images/bizinsider.png" alt="Business Insider" height="40">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
              <img src="./images/tnw.png" alt="TNW" height="38">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Pricing -->
  <section id="pricing">
    <div class="container py-3">
      <header>
        <div class="pricing-header p-3 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
          <h2 class="display-4 fw-normal text-body-emphasis">A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
          <p class="fs-5 text-body-secondary">Simple and affordable price plans for you and your dog.</p>
        </div>
      </header>

      <main>
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 mb-3 text-center">

          <div class="col">
            <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h3 class="my-0 fw-normal">Chihuahua</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-title pricing-card-title fs-1">$0<small class="text-body-secondary fw-light">/mo</small></p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>5 Matches Per Day</li>
                  <li>10 Messages Per Day</li>
                  <li>Unlimited App Usage</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h3 class="my-0 fw-normal">Labrador</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15<small class="text-body-secondary fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>Unlimited Matches</li>
                  <li>Unlimited Messages</li>
                  <li>Unlimited App Usage</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-dark">Get started</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm border-primary">
              <div class="card-header py-3 text-bg-dark border-primary">
                <h3 class="my-0 fw-normal">Mastiff</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29<small class="text-body-secondary fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>Pirority Listing</li>
                  <li>Unlimited Matches & Messages</li>
                  <li>Unlimited App Usage</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-dark">Contact us</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <section id="footer" class="gradient-background">
    <div class="container">
      <footer class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-5 py-2 pt-4">

        <div class="col mb-3">
          <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none">
            <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32">
                <use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use>
              </svg>
          </a>
          <p class="text-body-secondary">© TinDog</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col mb-3">
        </div>

        <div class="col mb-3">
          <h5>Section</h5>
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Features</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">FAQs</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col mb-3">
          <h5>Section</h5>
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Features</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">FAQs</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col mb-3">
          <h5>Section</h5>
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Features</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">FAQs</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-body-secondary">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>

  </section>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You saved my life which was almost dying out of frustration!! Thank you so much, I accepted your answer which was phenomenal!! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the placement of your container. In the code snippet, you're using the container class with the `col-xxl-8` class. Ensure that the container is wrapping the entire content you want to center, and the col-xxl-8 class is applied correctly.

and think you should check all container classes of feature section as like

`col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6` for the image container and `col-lg-6` for the text container.

Comment: The problem was actually caused by an oversized section on the page and I anyhow solved the issue in some other way. But I still really appreciate your effort in offering a helping hand, thank you so much for your reply anyways!